# ArrayList Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort even and odds using array list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortedEvensAndOdds {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> evenPrint = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> oddPrint = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int odd[] = new int[25];
    int numOdd = 0;
    int even [] = new int[25];
    int numEven = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++) {
        int num = rnd.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (num%2 ==0) {
            even[numEven] = num;
            numEven++;
        } 
        else {
            odd[numOdd] = num;
            numOdd++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++)
        evenPrint.add(even[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++)
        oddPrint.add(odd[i]);
    Collections.sort(evenPrint);
    Collections.sort(oddPrint);
    System.out.println("Even:");
    for (int i=0;i<numEven;i++) 
        System.out.print(evenPrint.get(i)  + " ");
    System.out.println("\nOdd:");
    for (int i=0;i<numOdd;i++) 
        System.out.print(oddPrint.get(i)  + " ");


}
}
```

this is my output

```
Even:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 6 14 28 36 38 54  
Odd:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do i prevent all the 0's

btw, if i take out the "Collections.sort()" method it will be

```
Even:
16 32 22 54 90 70 50 60 40 12 60 78 86 52 
Odd:
59 35 53 35 87 67 75 33 75 59 87
```

so this tells me that somthing is going wrong with the sorting
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a array like this: `int odd[] = new int[25];` what you gets it's a array of zeros, 25 of them. That's because `int` cannot be null.

So when you sort all the zeros at the end of your array are moved to the beginning of the array fe. before `1,5,9,13,19,0,0,0,0` was sorted to `0,0,0,0,1,5,9,13,19` and because you print only to index where you know that you assiged number there

```
for (int i=0;i<numEven;i++) 
    System.out.print(evenPrint.get(i)  + " ");
```

Notice numEven. It is not printing whole array. To print whole array you should rather use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < evenPrint.size(); i++)
    System.out.print(evenPrint.get(i) + " ");
```

You will get something like this:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 32 32 38 40 50 60 64 70 74 82 88 96`

**How to prevent this?**

Don't put every single element of array to list. Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++)
    evenPrint.add(even[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++)
    oddPrint.add(odd[i]);
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numEven; i++)
    evenPrint.add(even[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < numOdd; i++)
    oddPrint.add(odd[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2 loops `for (int i = 0; i < even.length; i++)`: instead of using `even.length` you should use `numEven` and `numOdd`, as you want to add just the quantity of even and odd numbers you've found. This will get rid of zeroes (when you initialize `odd` and `even` arrays, they're  filled with zeroes, which you are adding to `evenPrint` and `evenOdd` arrays). 
When you sort, all the zeroes go to the beginning, which doesn't happen when you don't sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the `int odd[]` and `int even[]` arrays elsewhere in your code, than you can get rid of those mystical zeros by omitting the arrays totally. You will get shorter - witch is always nice - and more readable code.

So if it is possible I would add the randomly generated numbers to the lists *directly*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    ArrayList<Integer> evenPrint = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> oddPrint = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        int num = rnd.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            evenPrint.add(num);
        } 
        else {
            oddPrint.add(num);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(evenPrint);
    Collections.sort(oddPrint);

    System.out.println("Even:");
    evenPrint.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));

    System.out.println("\nOdd:");
    oddPrint.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
}
```

**Notice**: I used [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) at the printing section for shortening.